# Hide Tab from Android ActionBar

Tags: android, android-tabs

I used the application-setup thing to make a tabs layout. It uses the action bar and a ViewPager in a layout to display a number of tabs. I currently have two tabs.

However I want to add a third tab, that will be hidden unless a special button in one of the tab-fragments is pushed. On button push I thought the application could slide over to the hidden tab and make it visible. Sliding back would make it hidden again.

1. Is this even possible in Android as it is? :)
2. How would I implement this with my current form of tab-management? I found some questions like this about people using the TabActivity or TabHosts in the layout. Would it be easier with one of the two implementations?

If you need any source code just ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, what you're asking can be done.

**In a nutshell**:

In your `onClickListener` for the `Button` you've designated to make the hidden tab visible, you should call `ActionBar.addTab`.

**Adding the new `Fragment`**

Depending on the layout that contains your `Fragments`, you could call `FragmentTransaction.hide` and `FragmentTransaction.show`, but otherwise I would assume you're adding the `Fragment` dynamically and therefore using a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, in which case add your new `Fragment` to your `List`.

**Links**

[ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) - [addTab](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#addTab%28android.app.ActionBar.Tab%29)

[FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) - [hide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide%28android.app.Fragment%29), [show](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show%28android.app.Fragment%29)

You should also read up on the [Adding Fragments docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding).

**Here's a very basic example:**

**ViewPager's Adapter**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

/**
 * The list of {@link Fragment}s used in the adapter
 */
private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

/**
 * Constructor for <code>PagerAdapter</code>
 * 
 * @param fm The {@link FragmentManager} to use.
 */
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

/**
 * Adds a new {@link Fragment} to the adapter
 * 
 * @param fragment The new {@link Fragment} to add to the list
 */
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    mFragments.add(fragment);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
    }
}
```

**Dummy Fragment**

```
public static final class DummyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    /**
     * Empty constructor as per the {@link Fragment} docs
     */
    public DummyFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * @param color The color to make the root view
     * @return A new instance of {@link DummyFragment}
     */
    public static DummyFragment getInstance(int color) {
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("color", color);
        final DummyFragment fragment = new DummyFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
        rootView.setBackgroundColor(getArguments().getInt("color"));
        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // This should be your Button
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // This adds the new tab
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).addTab(2, Color.BLUE);
        }
   }
```

**Called to add each Fragment**

```
    /**
 * Used to add a new {@link Fragment} to {@link ViewPager}'s adapter and
 * adds a new {@link Tab} to the {@link ActionBar}.
 * 
 * @param pageTitle The title of the tab
 * @param color The background color of the {@link Fragment}
 */
public void addTab(int pageTitle, int color) {
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(DummyFragment.getInstance(color));
    mActionBar.addTab(mActionBar.newTab()
            .setText("" + pageTitle)
            .setTabListener(this));
}
```

Comment: wow thanks for your answer. I'm currently still going through the code, seeing where I would have to add what in my code (and change certain parts :P)

Currently my application is based on a FragmentActivity that implements ActionBar.TabListener
What would I have to do to call the Pageradapter from the activity?

Comment: You'd just create a new `PagerAdapter` object.

`new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager())`

Comment: Ah yea I got it to work now. However another question:

public void addTab(int pageTitle, int color) {
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(DummyFragment.getInstance(color));
    mActionBar.addTab(mActionBar.newTab()
            .setText("" + pageTitle)
            .setTabListener(this));
}

Can't be run from a fragment, can it? It would have to be from the base-fragment activity, right? Should I use intents to make new fragments then? Or static access?

Comment: No, it can. Look at the `Fragment` I posted and notice how I call it. I cast the `Activity` that holds the method on `getActivity`. If you want to know more about calling methods from an `Activity` within a `Fragment`, you  should google "Calling Activity methods from Fragment" or something similar.

Comment: Ah thanks. Didn't see that. I already gave you the accept, thanks for the awesome help. Though I'd still have two questions on how to implement things :P Tabs are relatively new to me:

How could I get rid of said tab when sliding off it? (aka if the tab is made it should request focus. If the user slides away from it, the tab should disappear (or at least call a method to promt the user) --> actually two questions in one^^ Thanks in advance already!!

Comment: Look into [ViewPager.onPageChangeListner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) and [ActionBar.removeTab()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#removeTabAt(int))